# how to ignore upper/lower case in array check javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

im doing a check if a object matches a default value, however i don't care about upper/lower case differences.
Current function:

```
function checkSingleDifference(property) {
    if ($scope.defaultsAvailable === false) {
        console.log("default are not available!");
        return false;
    } else if (!$scope.machinedefaults || !$scope.machine) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return $scope.machinedefaults[property] !== undefined && $scope.machinedefaults[property] !== $scope.machine[property];
    }
}
```

The return value in CheckSingleDifference is the objects that do not match.
since the objects that are being checked are arrays, toUpperCase does not work. 
is it possible to handle this in a java script only way, or is it necessary to modify the objects in php?

expected values are 2 strings within a object so for example:
`machinedefaults[property] = "One"
machine[property] = "one"` then i don't want it to return these values.

thanks.

**UPDATE**
solution:

```
function checkSingleDifference(property) {
    if ($scope.defaultsAvailable === false) {
        console.log("default are not available!");
        return false;
    } else if (!$scope.machinedefaults || !$scope.machine) {
        return false;
    }
    if($scope.machinedefaults[property] !== undefined && $scope.machinedefaults[property].toLowerCase() !== $scope.machine[property].toLowerCase()) {
        return $scope.machinedefaults[property] !== undefined && $scope.machinedefaults[property] !== $scope.machine[property] ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the sample input and expected output.

Comment: And reduce your code to only add the relevant information

Comment: use $scope.machinedefaults[property].toUpperCase() !== $scope.machine[property].toUpperCase()

Comment: i can't understand what you want, can you explain better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still convert the strings it doesn't matter that they are in an array (or an object):

```
return $scope.machinedefaults[property] !== undefined &&
  $scope.machinedefaults[property].toLowerCase() !== $scope.machine[property].toLowerCase();
```

Comment: if i implement this it somehow always passes the check. see updated question.

Comment: never mind, i just had a brainfart, accepted as answer.